# implement gnome-cupertino theme at its best

Tags: themes

I have seen [this](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=147061) theme, I installed it, but it still looks pretty different from the promises (look at the picture). As you can see my result (on the right) is pretty different from promised version (on the left). Does someone ever tried with a real success this themes and how? [image: On the left the theme as sponsored, on the right my results]

Comment: Did you change your theme under `Right Click -> Change Desktop Background`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things are responsible for what we see on screen:

- the desktop background (to the extent its visible)
- the "gtk" theme
- the icon theme
- the window manager theme

The "gtk" theme affects most of the window that you see in your program except for regions such as the title bar, the maximize/minimize/close buttons (to the left or right of the title bar), and the thickness and color of windows borders.

(*I maybe stating the obvious here but you need to make sure that you're installing the GNOME theme that is appropriate to your GNOME version. Of late, there have been significant changes in the GUI of GNOME apps.* The theme you linked to has been updated to accommodate GNOME 3.6.x.)

What you have installed is the gtk theme. So, only specific aspects of your program's window are affected. If you want the "whole appearance", you may have to download the relevant icon theme and possibly even a window manager theme. I'm afraid you'll have to do this on your own by contacting the gtk theme's developer and asking about the icon theme and the window border theme. The link you provided has some information on this.

Comment: And let's not forget, that file browser in the picture **is not Nautilus**. So if the theme was made specifically for that File browser (Nemo?) it obviously won't look the same on Nautilus.

Comment: The left upper one or the right lower one? I think the former may be Nautilus. IDK, I'm on Lubuntu.

Comment: The left one, I however see that in the link Nautilus 3.6 is also displayed and it looks more or less  like the one from the OP which  leads me to say @Mariano, if you want your file browser to look like the one you're comparing Nautilus to, download it. That's not Nautilus.

Comment: What I really don't know is how to replace the path and shows it in the way in which is shown usr/share/themes

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you feel you need to "replace the path"? If at all, you may want to create `~/.themes` for your gtk themes and `~/.icons` for your icon themes. That way, you don't disturb /usr/share/themes and other users can choose to have their own themes and icons. (or just use the system ones).

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean "the way in which path is display" (I don't want to chage the path at all, lol).In the example is showing like right-arrow style, I shown the path as single-bubble style. :D

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried to get the exact publicized theme appearance for Gnome Cupertino. A trick that you can try out is to edit/customize the .css files according to your own liking:

cd /usr/share/themes (or the installation directory for the desired theme)
cd Gnome-Cupertino-unity/gtk-3.0

Now edit the contents of the file gtk.css, the file contains some elementary instructions to tweak certain parts of themes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you downloaded the theme and copy pasted the gnome-cupertino folder in `/usr/share/themes`,this is what you have to do *next*:

1. The file manager used in left screenshot is ***Marlin***.To install it,use these commands

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install marlin
   ```
2. Next you need to apply Elementary icon theme(this is used in screenshot!).Commands are

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/icons
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install elementary-icons
   ```

Now Gnome-Cupertino is *fully* applied :)